# devtools::check() F used instead of FALSE Execution halted ，R

Tags: r

my function and comment is:

```
#' @examples  check_duplication(iris,col_names = "Sepal.Length",check_type = F)
#             check_duplication(iris,col_names = "Sepal.Width")
check_duplication <- function(data,col_names,check_type=T){

  if(check_type){ data <- as.data.frame(data)}
  duplicate_nums<- nrow(data)-nrow(as.data.frame(base::unique(data[,col_names])))

  return(duplicate_nums)
}
```

it works will on `testthat` test and  console 
when i used devtools::check(),
it reports error

i know when i use F instead False ,this error would'd happan, but what cause this matter?

```
checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in ‘datools-Ex.R’ failed
  The error most likely occurred in:

  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: check_duplication
  > ### Title: check data unique
  > ### Aliases: check_duplication
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  >  check_duplication(iris,col_names = "Sepal.Length",check_type = F)
  Error in check_duplication(iris, col_names = "Sepal.Length", check_type = F) : 
    F used instead of FALSE
  Execution halted
```

i have two question :

> 1. how to solve this error
> 2. what's difference between TRUE and F  in R

thanks  for your help ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FALSE` instead of `F`, as the message suggests.

`F` is a variable, `FALSE` is a constant.  Using `F` is dangerous because a user might have code like `F <- 100` and then with your default `check_type = F`,

```
if (check_type) { data <- as.data.frame(data)}
```

will execute the clause, since `100` evaluates the same as `TRUE`.

If a user tried

```
FALSE <- 100
```

it would be flagged as a syntax error.